# using StringReplace and StringPattern to convert exp(...) to Exp[....]

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation, regular-expressions

I am looking at a file generated by another CAS. I'd like to convert it to Mathematica syntax.

Only issue is how to convert `exp(....)` to `Exp[....]`. I am using `StringReplace` with pattern to do the replacement but it is not catching all possible cases. I am not good at regular expressions in Mathematica.

Here are 5 simple input examples to test with

```
ClearAll[z]
str1 = "exp(x)^2";
str2 = "exp((x+2))";
str3 = "exp( (x+2) * exp(exp(x)+2) )";
str4 = "(4*x)/exp((x-(2/5))/((3/(exp(x)+5))*4+(x-(2-x))*x))+4"
str5="(20*x^4+(-30)*x^3+12*x^2+4*x)*exp(x)^2+(200*x^4+(-300)*x^3+300*x^2+(-236)*x)*exp(x)+(500*x^4+(-750)*x^3+1500*x^2+(-1400)*x+720)"
```

These should become

```
str1 = "Exp[x]^2";
str2 = "Exp[(x+2)]";
str3 = "Exp[ (x+2) * Exp[Exp[x]+2]  ]";
str4 = "(4*x)/Exp[(x-(2/5))/((3/(Exp[x]+5))*4+(x-(2-x))*x)]+4"
str5 = "(20*x^4+(-30)*x^3+12*x^2+4*x)*Exp[x]^2+(200*x^4+(-300)*x^3+300*x^2+(-236)*x)*Exp[x]+(500*x^4+(-750)*x^3+1500*x^2+(-1400)*x+720)"
```

This is what I tried among many other things

```
StringReplace[str, "exp(" ~~ z__ ~~ ")" :> "Exp[" ~~ z ~~ "]"]
```

Only the first and second worked.
The third one, it did not change any of the internal ones. it failed on `str4` and `str5` also.

Any suggestions how to do this conversion all in one command? Either using string patterns or regular expression in Mathematica.

I am using version 12.3.1

Comment: As far as I understand `StringReplace` is indeed a wolframized version of extended regular expressions. In the case of nested parentheses it's noteworthy that extended regular expressions are simply not expressive enough construct to handle arbitrary counting and matching of nested parentheses, which is required here (unless you work around it with the `@` trick).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:** We can convert the strings to expressions without any string processing:

```
ClearAll[sR0]
sR0 = ToExpression[#, TraditionalForm] &;

sR0 /@ {str1, str2, str3, str4, str5} // Column
```

[image]

If you need to get strings as output wrap the expression with `ToString[#, InputForm]&` using the third argument of `ToExpression`:

```
ClearAll[sR01]
sR01 = ToExpression[#, TraditionalForm, ToString[#, InputForm] &] &;

sR01 /@ {str1, str2, str3, str4, str5}
```

> ```
> {"E^(2*x)", 
>  "E^(2 + x)", 
>  "E^(E^(2 + E^x)*(2 + x))",
>  "4 + (4*x)/E^((-2/5 + x)/(12/(5 + E^x) + x*(-2 + 2*x)))",
>  "720 - 1400*x + 1500*x^2 - 750*x^3 + 500*x^4 +
>     E^(2*x)*(4*x + 12*x^2 - 30*x^3 + 20*x^4) + 
>     E^x*(-236*x + 300*x^2 - 300*x^3 + 200*x^4)"}
> ```

**Original answer:**

```
ClearAll[sR]
sR = StringReplace[#, "exp(" ~~ Shortest[z__] ~~ ")" /; 
   Equal @@ (StringCount[z, #] & /@ {"(", ")"}) :> 
 "Exp[" <> sR @ z <> "]"] &;

sR /@ {str1, str2, str3, str4, str5}
```

> ```
> {"Exp[x]^2",
>  "Exp[(x+2)]",
>  "Exp[ (x+2) * Exp[Exp[x]+2] ]", 
>  "(4*x)/Exp[(x-(2/5))/((3/(Exp[x]+5))*4+(x-(2-x))*x)]+4", 
>  "(20*x^4+(-30)*x^3+12*x^2+4*x)*Exp[x]^2+(200*x^4+(-300)*x^3+300*x^2+
>    (-236)*x)*Exp[x]+(500*x^4+(-750)*x^3+1500*x^2+(-1400)*x+720)"}
> ```

You can also use `FixedPoint` as follows:

```
ClearAll[sR2]
sR2 = FixedPoint[StringReplace[
     "exp(" ~~ Shortest[z__] ~~ ")" /; 
       Equal @@ (StringCount[z, #] & /@ {"(", ")"}) :> 
      "Exp[" <> z <> "]"], #] &;

sR2 /@ {str1, str2, str3, str4, str5} == sR /@ {str1, str2, str3, str4, str5}
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it on the main files, there are cases where it does not work. Here is one `str4="(20*x^4+(-30)*x^3+12*x^2+4*x)*exp(x)^2+(200*x^4+(-300)*x^3+300*x^2+(-236)*x)*exp(x)+(500*x^4+(-750)*x^3+1500*x^2+(-1400)*x+720)"`  it gives `"(20*x^4+(-30)*x^3+12*x^2+4*x)*Exp[x)^2+(200*x^4+(-300)*x^3+300*x^2+(-
236)*x)*Exp[x)+(500*x^4+(-750)*x^3+1500*x^2+(-1400]*x+720]"`  I will add this example to my question for completion.

Comment: Also please note that `str4` test also did not pass. It generated `Exp[x)` there as well.

Comment: @Nasser, please see the updated version.

Comment: Thanks for the update. But for `str5` it still gives `Exp[x)^2`

Comment: @Nasser, updated version works for `str1` thru `str5` (will need another update for `str6`:)

Comment: Thanks. I will try it on the file, it has over 10,000 cases. It works now on all 5 cases. There is supposed to be a way to do this using regular expressions using sed, as given in  [How to replace paired square brackets with other syntax with sed?](https://newbedev.com/how-to-replace-paired-square-brackets-with-other-syntax-with-sed) but I could not make it work.

Answer (score 8):

A simple trick is to notice that in Mathematica, `Exp[x]` can be written as `Exp@(x)` where the `@` symbol has [very high precedence](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html). A replacement of the string `"exp"` by the string `"Exp@"` therefore does the necessary conversion without needing any bracket-matching logic:

```
convert[s_String] := ToExpression[StringReplace[s, "exp" -> "Exp@"]]

convert[str1]
(*    E^(2 x)    *)

convert[str2]
(*    E^(2 + x)    *)

convert[str3]
(*    E^(E^(2 + E^x) (2 + x))    *)

convert[str4]
(*    4 + 4 E^(-((-(2/5) + x)/(12/(5 + E^x) + x (-2 + 2 x)))) x    *)

convert[str5]
(*    720 - 1400 x + 1500 x^2 - 750 x^3 + 500 x^4 + E^(2 x) (4 x + 12 x^2 - 30 x^3 + 20 x^4) + E^x (-236 x + 300 x^2 - 300 x^3 + 200 x^4)    *)
```

If you want pretty string forms (instead of automatic evaluation with [`ToExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToExpression.html) as above), use an [invisible application](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/InvisibleApplication.html) esc-@-esc to hide the `@` symbols:

```
convert2[s_String] := StringReplace[s, "exp" -> "Exp\[InvisibleApplication]"]

convert2[str1]
(*    "Exp\[InvisibleApplication](x)^2"    *)
(*    actually looks like "Exp(x)^2" in the front-end but is
      correct Mathematica syntax                                *)

ToExpression[%]
(*    E^(2 x)    *)
```